# Saving asmack Vcard Avatars

Tags: java, android, asmack

I'm developing a chat app using asmack buddycloud library, the issue that I have at moment is I can receive images from the user's vcard using this code:

```
for (RosterEntry rosterEntry : roster.getEntries()) {
    String  senderusername = rosterEntry.getUser();
    String  senderrealname = rosterEntry.getName();
    //   String  sendermessage =  ?????
    VCard vcard = new VCard();
    try {
        vcard.load(connection, ""+senderusername+"");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // load someone's VCard
    byte[] senderimage = vcard.getAvatar();
}
```

but I cannot save it to the disk (external), and googling didn't really help.

Could you guys throw a help here, please? thanks

Comment: The buddycloud version of aSmack is 4 years old. I suggest you try an up-to-date version of aSmack.

Comment: well i found it less problematic than rest dude

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  vcard.load(connection,  ""+senderusername+"@"+SERVICE_NAME);
  byte[] senderimage = vcard.getAvatar();
} catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();}
```

Seems you are not loading VCard properly.
replace sendername with sendername+"@"+SERVICE_NAME like shown above.

After getting the user's image byte array you can easily convert in into String and then Base64 and finally save it in the form of image in the internal storage. The same approach for me is working fine.
Hope this works.